# How to get data from Mixpanel using RMixpanel?

Tags: r, rcurl, mixpanel

I am running the following script to extract data from MixPanel:

```
library(RMixpanel)
account<- mixpanelCreateAccount("abc", token = "123", secret = "456", key = "789")
mixpanelGetFunnelList(account)
```

From all the examples I have seen, these commands should work but after entering the last command, I am getting the following error:

> Error in file(file, "r") : cannot open the connection
>
> In addition: Warning messages:
>
> 1: running command 'curl -s -S "https://456@mixpanel.com/api/2.0/funnels/list/?"  -o "temp_xyz.txt"' had status 127
>
> 2: In download.file(url, filePath, "curl", quiet = TRUE) :
>     download had nonzero exit status
>
> 3: In file(file, "r") :
>     cannot open file 'temp_xyz.txt': No such file or directory

I searched this error and the only possible explanation was that I don't have curl installed on my system but this shouldn't be an issue since while installing RMixpanel, RCurl was also installed. Still I have installed curl on my system and the same error is existing.

Also, when I copy pasted the url in error 1 in my browser, it was working and giving correct results.

Can someone guide me what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the maintainer of the package `RMixpanel`. The package until version 0.5-2 used

```
download.file(url, filePath, "curl", quiet=TRUE)
```

which did not work on some systems (Windows?). Now I replaced it by using

```
getURL()
```

from package `RCurl` which should work correct. It will be available as of tomorrow on CRAN (version 0.6-0), or already now using the [github source](https://github.com/ploner/RMixpanel)